# How to store text file NoSQL DB? Which NOSQL should I use? How to integrate it with flask in python?

Tags: json, flask, nosql

How to store a text file in a NOSQL Database, such that we can retrieve the file faster and without any changes in data. Which NOSQL Database is preferred for this, Also I want to integrate it with Flask so which library should i use?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a design issue that you are facing. You should not store text files in a database, and store the text as a Json object (strings, arrays, etc) instead. You could use any NoSQL database, for example, MongoDB. A MongoDB API for python called [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) can be used, along with flask.